# Passando um Array de Strings para um preparedStatement?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Estou tentando passando um array de Strings para um `preparedStatement`, mas ta retornando essa exceção:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: This operation is not supported.
>     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.createArrayOf(SQLServerConnection.java:2763)
>     at entity.dao.getRecords(Dao.java:168)
>     at entity.dao.main(Dao.java:227)
> ```

Meu código está assim:

```
public List<Record> getRecords() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "select * from table where clause in (?)";

        PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("string1");
        strings.add("string2");
        strings.add("string3");

        Array array = this.connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", strings.toArray());

        ps.setArray(1, array);

        ResultSet executeQuery = ps.executeQuery();
        List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
        Record record;
        while (executeQuery.next()) {
            // ...
        }
        return records;
    }
```

a linha da exceção é:

```
Array array = this.connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", strings.toArray());
```

e ocorre quando eu tento criar o array.

Já procurei em todo canto, como passar um Array para um preparedStatement, e todo mundo fala pra fazer assim, mas parece não funcionar com o SQLServer.

Comment: Henrique, não precisa citar as tags no titulo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse problema não tem solução. O driver do SQLServer para Java não suporta a fetature de incluir arrays.

Essa exceção é lançada quando o driver que está usando não suporta ou não implementou uma função opcional do JDBC.

A [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLFeatureNotSupportedException.html) da Oracle explica exatamente isso.

Pelo o que andei pesquisando, diversos bancos/drivers deixam de implementar uma feature ou outra.

---

Como alternativa, você pode usar um `StringBuilder` e separar suas clausulas com vírgula e fazer um `setString()` normal. Por exemplo:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("string1");
strings.add("string2");
strings.add("string3");
.
.
.
strings.add("stringN");

//itera a lista  
StringBuilder ins = new StringBuilder();
for(String val : strings) {
  ins.append(val);
  ins.append(", ");
}
//remove o ultimo ", "
ins.delete((ins.length() - 2), ins.length());

//finalmente inclui no PreparedStatement
ps.setString(1, ins.toString());
```

---

Para referência, [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray-int-java.sql.Array-) está a documentação do método `setArray()`. Nela está descrito o motivo pelo qual a `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` pode ser lançada.

Comment: Seria interessante você adicionar alguma fonte confirmando isso que você afirmou na primeira linha da pergunta.

Comment: @diegofm editei a resposta. A fonte é a própria documentação do método `setArray()`. Ela explicita o motivo pelo qual a exceção pode ser lançada. A documentação diz: _Throws: `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` - if the JDBC driver does not support this method_

Comment: Entendi, passou despercebido quando li. Se não se encomodar, atualizei a documentação pra versão mais recente, qualquer coisa, você pode fazer o rollback :)

Comment: quando li a documentação, eu li isso. já fiquei sabendo o motivo por não rodar. eu queria mesmo era a solução, essa que você passou, eu já estou utilizando, mas valeu!!

Comment: "eu queria mesmo era a solução": tem solução? ._.